# What is the source of this story about suffering and having a dream about it..?

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends

I remember a story about a person that suffered very much and went to see a certain rebbe to help him.  While waiting he feel asleep and had a dream where he saw his mitzvos and aveiros and the avairos fair outweighed the mitzvos - but then the angels brought in more trucks and starting unloading bags onto the side of merit.  He asked one of the angels what are these and the angel said this is the suffering that you went through.  As they unloaded the bags the scale started to raise the side of merit and as the emptied out the last of the bags from the truck the scale was exactly even.  He woke up screaming "more suffering!! I need more suffering"

That's basically the story.  Does anyone know the source?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it looks familiar. Maybe I saw this in the "High Holiday Survival Guide" by Shimon Apisdorf? Or, it sounds like something in Book of Our Heritage by Eliyahu Kitov. The 2nd book (Kitov) is online. I'll see if I can locate the survival kit in my home.